# How can I alias an environment variable when executing a script?

Tags: environment-variables

My Node script uses an environment variable to establish a connection to a Postgres database, called `POSTGRES_CONNECTION`.

However, it's deployed to Heroku, which names the connection string `DATABASE_URL`.

Is there an elegant way to "map" the `DATABASE_URL` value to `POSTGRES_CONNECTION`, preferably outside the code? I know I can do something like `connectToPostgres(process.env.POSTGRES_CONNECTION ? process.env.POSTGRES_CONNECTION : process.env.DATABASE_URL)`, but it seems to me like polluting my code with environment-specific configuration, which I'd like to avoid.

Alternatively I could rename our development variable (`POSTGRES_CONNECTION`), but given that we have other databases as well, `DATABASE_URL` seems rather generic, and it's also already being used in several lower environments.

Answer (score 0):

Seems obvious, but the cleanest way I've come up with is to confine the alias to the package.json scripts and use a different script for Heroku.

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku": "POSTGRES_CONNECTION=$DATABASE_URL npm start"
  }
}
```

**Procfile**

```
web: npm run heroku
```